# Get values by index tables on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
Table1 (id, name, var1, var2, var3)

Vars (id, name)
```

With examples of rows:

**Table1:**

```
1, John, 3, 6, 7
2, Peter, 1, 4, 3
```

**Table Two (Vars):**

```
1, Cat
2, Dog
3, Fish
4, Cow
5, Goat
6, Bear
7, Bird
8, Koala
9, Lion
10, Frog
```

The desideres output is:

```
1, John, Fish, Bear, Bird
2, Peter, Cat, Cow, Fish
```

I have tried to use some `INNER JOINS` but I think I'm doing in wrong way, because I can't get the right result, How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `join` the `vars` table thrice. or as many times as the number of vars on a row.

```
select t1.id, t1.name, v1.name, v2.name, v3.name
from table1 t1
join vars v1 on v1.id = t1.var1
join vars v2 on v2.id = t1.var2
join vars v3 on v3.id = t1.var3
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west, but please edit `var1, var2, var3` in join condition :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to handle missing values:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, v1.name AS name_1, v2.name AS name_2, v3.name AS name_3
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Vars v1
  ON t1.var1 = v1.id
LEFT JOIN Vars v2
  ON t1.var2 = v2.id
LEFT JOIN Vars v3
  ON t1.var3 = v3.id
```

Comment: @alessadro Are var1, var2, var3 set as `NOT NULL`? If no check solution for data `1, John, 3, 6, NULL`